# Removing manufacturer in xcart

Tags: x-cart

I am using `xcart` 4.7.  After removing a manufacturer, all products renamed as restored products and all details are corrupted.  I tried to database integrity checking but no result.

Comment: How many languages do you use ?

Comment: currently only english

Comment: Which exact X-Cart version do you use ?

Comment: x-cart-4.7.5platinum

Comment: Do you have any errors on your var/log folder ? Is it possible to check the result for these queries SELECT name,value FROM xcart_config WHERE name LIKE '%default_%_language%';  SHOW tables LIKE 'xcart_products_lng%';

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, Sarath S Rajendran, for the bug localization.

Fixed in X-Cart 4.7.8. Custom code hasn't to call func_delete_product() without params.

Wrong calls

```
func_delete_product();
func_delete_product(0);
func_delete_product('');
func_delete_product(null);
```

Correct calls

```
func_delete_product(3123);
func_delete_product(3123,false);
func_delete_product(0,false,true);
```