# Xcart 4.7.5 : All products renamed as restored_product and corrupt the price and other values

Tags: x-cart

I currently working on a ecommerce site using xcart 4.7.5. As per the  client requirement i wrote some custom modules for csv uploads of products.Everything working fine. But sometimes all products renamed as restored_products and corrupt the product database values. i dont know what happened.I am so confused here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing manufacturer in xcart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42267453/removing-manufacturer-in-xcart)

Answer (score 2):

Found it. its just beacause of function func_delete_product($productid).here if the productis null or empty they just erase all details from product_lng table. So i added some validations to it and now its works fine.

Comment: Hello Sarath S Rajendran, can you please share more details on how do you exactly fixed it. Somehow I got same errors, and since it was on test site several months ago it is impossible to understand what trigger this error. comment by [Syracuse Web Design](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2116026/syracuse-web-design), incorrectly pass as answer on this question.

Comment: please look at the  func_delete_product() function in include/func/func.product.php. I just added the following validation
if($productid=="" || !empty($productid)){
 return false;
}else{
 continue;
}